# response is working but result is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple POST request using fetch()

```
fetch('/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: 'test@gmail.com', password: 'test' }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        response.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
```

the response is valid and gives the JSON that I am expecting `{ 'id':1 }` but the result just returns `undefined` every time. Have I written something incorrectly or am I missing something really simple?

Comment: `return response.json();` - otherwise the first `.then` returns `undefined` - just like any function, without a `return` nothing (undefined) is returned

Comment: wow...I can't believe that was it the whole time...works now! Thanks!

Comment: For anyone that sees this in the future: the reason the code did not work was because the line that I wanted to return had a semicolon. Arrow functions act as expressions and return the last line without a semicolon...in this example undefined was being returned. I added a 'return' to the line but best practise would be to remove the semicolon!

Comment: That's not quite right, the semicolon is irrelevant, the `{}` is what makes the `return` required ... without `{}` the `return` would be implicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try return response on the first then:

```
.then((response) => {
   return response.json();
})
```

Comment: no no no no no ... either use async/await OR .then ... never both, and never like that

Comment: really, maybe just add a return inside the first then will solve the problem

Comment: exactly - that's how functions work - personally ... I'd do `then((response) => response.json())` - and that's where the OP probably got confused - the difference between having `{}` or not in single line arrow notation